# How I could validate a signature of a message?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

If I have the following data  “n = 221” and “e = 13  and I know that the receiver received M = 65”  with the signature= “C = 182”.
I dont want a answer just want to learn, so if anyone could give a example or path to follow. 
thanks a lot

Comment: Plain RSA verification is nothing more than modular exponentiation on the signature value. n is the modulus and e is the exponent. So what do you get if you perform that operation?

Comment: Side note, there are fast modular exponentiation functions that are much more performant than first exponentiation and then performing the modulus, but that's not an issue for such small values. Don't keep doing that for larger RSA keys though.

Comment: thanks a lot , I could solve, I just needed a clue :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography, but it has dupes on the crypto.SE site.